# How to send JSON?

Tags: vue.js

I would like to send to server JSON. I do it with next code:

```
            var JSONObj = { "bookname ":"VB BLACK BOOK", "price":500 };

            this.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/login', JSONObj).then(function (response) {
              console.log("server response: ", response.status)
            });
```

But in console I am get next error:

`Object {request: Object, data: "404 - Not Found↵↵Not Found↵↵Internal error information:↵No routes match path '/login'", status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", ok: false}`

Comment: The problem is with routing. There is no path that is mapped to `/login` in your code. If you could show more code, we can help you better.

Comment: http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?y6bzqvecjoy3

all app.js code

Comment: The code does not have anything to handle the post request. It should be on your backend code.

Comment: Oh, look like I understand problem. Vue wait for any answer from server? right?

Comment: Yes. If you are requesting something at some URI, that URI should exist in the first place. This is the basic of server-client applications.